# Obtener credenciales de base de datos desde un txt

Tags: php, apache

Estoy haciendo un desarrollo en PHP que requiere conexión a base de datos, actualmente las credenciales están escritas en el código.

```
$server = '255.255.255.255';
$user   = 'user';
$pass   = '<kjdhsadflkjhseuhdfsejhsuhksad';
$db     = 'database';
$conn   = new mysqli( $server, $user, $pass, $db );
```

Este método es el común entre los developers, sin embargo se ha considerado una práctica altamente peligrosa.

Hace un par de semanas revisando SO, vi un usuario sugiriendo a otro colaborador que pusiera esas credenciales fuera del contexto del script. El año pasado revisé un post de un developer que ponía sus credenciales en un archivo .txt y luego jalaba dicha información a su script del PHP, sin embargo no recuerdo el proceso.

Espero alguno pueda darme un poco de orientación de este tema.

Comment: Y esa información dentro del _.txt_ ¿Qué formato tenía, texto plano o encriptado? Me llama bastante la atención el planteamiento, de ahí la pregunta.

Comment: Era texto plano, de hecho era una especie de asignación de variables con lo que después eran llamadas al PHP

Comment: Hola Alberto, estaba revisando respuestas ¿Te sirvió la info de la respuesta? Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Voy a plantear dos opciones.
Hay varias formas de obtener el contenido de un archivo *.txt*.

Un par de ejemplos:

```
$data=explode("\n", file_get_contents('data.txt'));
```

ó

```
$data=file('data.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

### Opción 1

El archivo solo contiene los valores de la conexión.

**Archivo *.txt***

```
127.0.0.1
root
root
dbname
```

La variable `$data` tendría una salida (*var_dump*) similar a esto:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
  1 => string 'root' (length=4)
  2 => string 'root' (length=4)
  3 => string 'dbname' (length=6)
```

Solo nos quedaría asignar cada elemento del *array* a cada variable.
Quedaría algo así:

```
$data=explode("\n", file_get_contents('data.txt'));
$host=$data[0];
$user=$data[1];
$pass=$data[2];
$db  =$data[3];
$conn=new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
```

### Opción 2

El archivo contiene tanto los valores de la conexión, como el nombre de las variables.

**Archivo *.txt***

```
host=127.0.0.1
user=root
pass=root
db=quiniela_test
```

La variable `$data` tendría una salida (*var_dump*) similar a esto:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'host=127.0.0.1' (length=14)
  1 => string 'user=root' (length=9)
  2 => string 'pass=root' (length=9)
  3 => string 'db=dbname' (length=9)
```

Solo hay que crear un bucle para signar los nombres de las variables automáticamente y su valor correspondiente.   Quedaría algo así:

```
$data=explode("\n", file_get_contents('data.txt'));
foreach($data as $value) {
    $item      =explode('=', $value);
    ${$item[0]}=$item[1];
}
$conn=new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
```

Si no he cometido algún error al redactarlo deberían funcionar las dos opciones.